# javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type Java Struts SOAP WSDL

Tags: java, soap, wsdl, struts

ok I have really a strange problem that I keep looking for solution in google and yahoo for almost 4 hours today. And I desperately looking for a solution.

```
public static String [] checkCardAccount(String cardNumber, String cardIssuer, String securityNumber){

        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL("http://localhost:8999/bankcard?wsdl");
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        QName qname = new QName("http://server.bcard.soap.com/","BankCardImplService");

        Service service = Service.create(url,qname);

        BankCard bankcard = service.getPort(BankCard.class);

        return bankcard.getCardClientData(cardNumber, cardIssuer);
    }
```

the above code is my client for accessing the SOAP service, it really works in a standalone java application but when I embed it to my Java Struts application it says the following error below

> javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Undefined port type:
>   {http://bankcard.api.com/}BankCard    at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:349)
>     at
>   com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.getPort(WSServiceDelegate.java:355)
>     at javax.xml.ws.Service.getPort(Service.java:161)   at
>   com.api.bankcard.BankCardClient.checkCardAccount(BankCardClient.java:25)
>     at com.action.CardregAction.execute(CardregAction.java:18)  at
>   org.apache.struts.chain.commands.servlet.ExecuteAction.execute(ExecuteAction.java:58)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.chain.commands.AbstractExecuteAction.execute(AbstractExecuteAction.java:67)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.chain.commands.ActionCommandBase.execute(ActionCommandBase.java:51)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.chain.generic.LookupCommand.execute(LookupCommand.java:305)
>     at
>   org.apache.commons.chain.impl.ChainBase.execute(ChainBase.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.chain.ComposableRequestProcessor.process(ComposableRequestProcessor.java:283)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1913)
>     at
>   org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doPost(ActionServlet.java:462)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:298)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:857)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:588)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

Now I really see that the problem is the target namespace because as I change it the error changes to that it says that the valid services is `{http://bankcard.api.com/}BankCard`

where I went wrong? this code works on standalone on Java Application but not in my Java Struts web app

Answer (score 6):

give endpointIneterface in @WebService annotation in the implementation class, if you dont give endpoint interface, you have to mention fully qualified port name while using getPort method.

service.getPort("PortQName",BankCard.class);

Comment: @anil kumar, could you please show an example how to mention fully qualified port name?

Answer (score 1):

You need to annotate the `BankCardImpl` class with `@WebService(name="BankCard")`
You can then use `service.getPort(BankCard.class);`

**OR**

If you just annotate it with `@WebService` or have given it another name, then you will need to provide more information to the `getPort()` method:

replace

```
BankCard bankcard = service.getPort(BankCard.class);
```

with

```
QName port_name = new QName("http://server.bcard.soap.com/","BankCardImplPort");
BankCard bankcard = service.getPort(port_name, BankCard.class);
```